# Converting PHP pagination to jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, class, pagination

Hey, I have been trying to get [this pagination class](http://phpsense.com/php/php-pagination-script.html) that I am using to be more ajaxy - meaning when I click on the page number like page [2] the data loads, but I want to load in the data without going to a different page (HTTP request in the background, with no page reloads).

Being new to both php and jquery, I am a little unsure on how to achieve this result, especially while using a php class.

This is what the main page looks like by the way:

```
<?php
$categoryId=$_GET['category'];
echo $categoryId;
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_page.js"></script>

<?php
    //Include the PS_Pagination class
    include('ps_pagination.php');
    //Connect to mysql db
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
    mysql_select_db('ajax_demo',$conn);
    $sql = "select * from explore where category='$categoryId'";
    //Create a PS_Pagination object
    $pager = new PS_Pagination($conn, $sql, 3, 11, 'param1=value1&param2=value2');
    //The paginate() function returns a mysql
    //result set for the current page
    $rs = $pager->paginate();
    //Loop through the result set

echo "<table width='800px'>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {            

                echo "<tr>";
                    echo"<td>";
                        echo $row['id'];
                    echo"</td>";

                    echo"<td>";
                        echo $row['site_description'];
                    echo"</td>";

                    echo"<td>";
                        echo $row['site_price'];
                    echo"</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

    }
echo "</table>";

        echo "<ul id='pagination'>";

            echo "<li>";
            //Display the navigation
            echo $pager->renderFullNav();
            echo "</li>";

        echo "</ul>";

?>

<div id="loading" ></div>
<div id="content" ></div>
```

Would I need to do something with this part of the class?, as seen above:

```
$pager = new PS_Pagination($conn, $sql, 3, 11, 'param1=value1&param2=value2');
```

Or this?:

```
echo $pager->renderFullNav();
```

I don't no much about jquery,but i guess I would start it like:

```
$("#pagination li").click(function() {
```

Then load something maybe...

I don't no. Any help on this would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What are the parameters for the `PS_Pagination` constructor?

Comment: the parameters can be found here: http://phpsense.com/php/php-pagination-script.html

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure how to go about it using that class, it seems it would be a bit tricky, as the script you make the ajax call to, to retrieve the data, will need to have access to the current PS_pagination instance.

Without the class though, it wouldnt be too tricky.

You would need a php script to actually return the data, which takes in the number of records per page, and the current page number. In this script, rather than returning the data, i return the html. So i take the data from the database, then generate the table. This means that all i have to do on success of ajax is replace what is in the able currently, with the new html that i get from this script. Heres an example..

```
//Current Page Number 
$page_num = isset($_GET['page_number']) ?  mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page_number']) : 1;

//Number of records to show on each page 
$num_records = isset($_GET['num_records_pp']) ?  mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['num_records_pp']) : 10;

//Row to start collecting data from 
$start_row = $num_records * ($page_num - 1);

//String to store html to return 
$return_html = '';

//SQL Query 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT $start_row, $num_records");

//Query success 
if($sql) {      
    //Construct html for table  
    $return_html = "<table width='800px'>";         

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)    {       

      $return_html .= "<tr>";       
      $return_html .= "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";        
      $return_html .= "<td>" . $row['site_description'] . "</td>";
      $return_html .= "<td>" . $row['site_price'] . "</td>"; 
      $return_html .= "</tr>";

    }       
    $return_html .= "</table>";

//Query Failed 
} else {

    $return_html = "<p class='error'>Error Fetching Data</p>";

}

return $return_html;
```

Then you just make a get request via ajax and pass the page number, and the number of rows you want.

```
$.get("get_data.php", { page_number: 1, num_records_pp: 20 },
   function(data){
     $('div#my_table').html(data);
   });
```

So, this query assumses that you have a div with an id of "my_table" which contains your table, it will then replace this with a new table consistion of just the data you requested.

This code was just to give you the jist, so i may have some errors in there, but hope it helps.

Comment: It's the sql injection vulnerability in your example I'm worried about most. You should really sanitize user input. Even if it's just an example IMHO. To illustrate my point, take this example, if `$_GET[ 'num_records_pp' ] = "10; DELETE * FROM USERS;"`... say bye bye to your user accounts for instance.

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for mentioning that, ive altered the above now slightly. I just overlooked it with it being an example, but then i probably shoudnt have :)